# Passing in arguments for evil-ex-command

Tags: evil

I understand that `evil-ex-define-cmd` allow me create my own ex commands.

Although in Vim, you were able to narrow down the search by doing something like

`:h <term>`

I'm not sure how to accomplish the same in evil, or if this is even possible.

Comment: I should specify: What I want to do is to take the arguments after `:h` and pass it into the function bound by `evil-ex-define-cmd` (this is currently `helm`).

Whether that is a useful activity is best left for another discussion

Comment: Look at the definition of ex commands reading in extra arguments.  I'll whip up a complete example later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ex command is just another function.  Evil defines a few extra interactive codes to retrieve what you've passed to it, `<a>` is the most generic one and returns the text after the command as is:

```
(evil-define-command my-help (arg)
  (interactive "<a>")
  (message "ARG: %s" arg))

(evil-ex-define-cmd "h[elp]" 'my-help)
```

`:h foo` will display "ARG: foo" in the echo area.  Extend this as you need for whatever you're doing with Helm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it appears that helm does not allow me to initialize searches like that